# is there a handler on socket receiving in android?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm trying to receiving some UDP packets at port 3000. However, except for the `while()` loop, i cannot find a way to detect whether and when the packet is received. I'm curious if there is a way to let me get informed when a packet is filled in, maybe a event handler or something like that? I'm using android API 10. Thanks.

Comment: [Literally the first thing I found after a google search](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/socket-programming/)

Comment: @ChrisCooney I've checked the site. I'm not sure if it works for UDP socket DataGramSocket. Also, I think the example in the link is using while() loop too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use DatagramSocket? Because in that case if you use the receive method it blocks until a datagram is received.